# Setting Data Driven Pages PDF File Name?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, data-driven-pages

I have a mapbook I created using ArcGIS Desktop 10.0 that has its index layer as a 4 digit number.

I just wanted to export my maps as PDFs so they only show the 4 digit number, at the moment they are showing the name of my mxd and the 4 digit number.

e.g. MyMapbook_5132

Is there a simply way I can export them to only show the numbers,

e.g. 5132.pdf rather than MyMapbook_5132.pdf

PS - my 4 digit number comes from a field within my index grid

Comment: It might help if you indicate what version of ArcMap are you using, and if are you using the Mapbook extension or Data Driven Pages.  If you are using DDP you might indicate where your number values come from, such as a page number or from the name or some other field in the index layer.

Comment: Hi Johns, I indicated what version I am using in the title, and I am using data driven pages, not a mapbook extension - thanks!

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to conain all critical information.  The title is not a part of the question. ArcGIS 10.0 is sufficiently ancient that you're not likely to find many folks still using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just solve this problem post-export using a wonderful piece of software by the name of [Advanced Renamer](https://www.advancedrenamer.com/). It is super easy to use, very versatile, works on all sorts of file types, and best of all it's free.